# Ajax call to JsonResult in Controller fails with 404 error, "resource not found"

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

Here is my ajax code in my "ManageUserRoles.cshtml":

```
//HIT THE DATABASE FOR USERNAME GIVING IT THIS USERNAME
function isUserValid(thisUser) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/Roles/isUserValid/" + thisUser,
        type: 'POST',
        success: handleResultResponseUserName,
        error: function (xhr) { alert("Error..."); }
    });
}


//handles data back from ajax call
//RESET INPUT IF NO USER IF FOUND IN USER'S TABLE
function handleResultResponseUserName(ResponseObject) {

    if (ResponseObject == "no user with this number") {

        $('#frmGetRoles').find('input[name="UserName"]').val(null);

    }
    else {

        //DO NOTHING

    }

}
```

Here is my JsonResult in my RolesController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult isUserValid(string username)
{
    var name = string.Empty;

    var CheckUserExists = (from c in _db.AspNetUsers
                       where (c.UserName.Equals(username))
                       select c);


    var results = new JsonResult();

    if (CheckUserExists.Any())
    {

        name = CheckUserExists.First().UserName;

    }

    else
    {
        name = "no user with this name in database";

    }
    return Json(name, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet); 
}
```

I've got almost exact code working in a different application and I cut and pasted into a new one where I am trying to use it for Roles management.

The json reference is there, and in web.config. But when I put a breakpoint inside the JsonResult, it never stops there and an error is returned from the client javascript (404 resource not found). There is no other json stuff being used in this new app . . .yet.

I can hit f5 and it returns:
http://localhost/StoreMasterSecure/Roles/ManageUserRoles 
which is the view that has the button that runs the ajax. It all gets to the ajax call and then nothing happens and Chrome Developer Tools console shows 404 error.

Even if I type in the URL the path, I get the resource not found 404 page:
http://localhost/StoreMaster/Roles/isValidUser/xxxx@xxx.com

(isValidUser is the JsonResult in the controller, in same controller that ManageUserRoles ActionResult exists and works)

Comment: You method is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` but you never pass the token (either pass it or remove the attribute) but why are you not using a `[Remote]` attribute? And typing the url wont work because your method is a POST, not a GET.

Comment: Stephen, I put the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in there because I saw it above all the other ActionResults. It doesn't work with it or without it. I took it off, tried to put [Remote] and it underlined and red with the explanation: "RemoteAttribute() is inaccessible due to its protection level." However, I didn't need this in my working application, which also uses POST method and works. The form field data gets to the .ajax call. But 404 resource not found is all I get.

Comment: (1) Your not understanding what the `RemoteAttribute` is - you apply it to your property. Refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). (2) You must remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` if you don't pass the token. (3) Your ajax options need to be `url: '@Url.Action("isUserValid", "Roles")',` and `data: { username: thisUser },`

Comment: Hmmm. (1) I will do the remote validation stuff later in development. Currently I just want any example of getting an ajax call to JsonResult to work. (2)Yes. It is removed for now. I was not logged in as a user. Still too early. Funny, but I've spent the last 3 weeks just getting Identity stuff to work, none of the CRUD stuff. oh boy. (3)Good news is your advice to change the ajax options worked! And I was off and running with my breakpoint being hit every time. So . . . Please make your comment an answer and I will accept it as the answer. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure you url's are correctly generated, use the `Url.Action()` method and pass the data using the ajax `data` option. Change your ajax to

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("isUserValid", "Roles")', // change this
    data: { username: thisUser }, // add this
    type: 'POST',
    success: handleResultResponseUserName,
    error: function (xhr) { alert("Error..."); }
});
```

You also need to remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attibute from your controller method since you not passing the token.

Side note: MVC comes with a `RemoteAttribute` to handle this scenario. Refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) which means you do not need your script.

Comment: I mean Remote Validation. Not sure, but your link explains how to do it in MVC 3. I'm in MVC 5 now and the teams at MS are going a million miles an hour.

Comment: Makes no difference - exactly the same code applies :)

Comment: Not sure. I used this in my CRUD project I was going to meld with my Authentication part. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation    Also, I will need to populate pulldowns and other "runtime" changes so just validating if value exists in database is just a start. If it works, I can get anything to work. Thank you.